# how to retrieve "shared" labeled folder/files from the gdata.docs.service.DocsService()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gdata, gdata-api

This is how I retrieve a list of files and folders from the root of a Google Drive account.

I've also printed out the `role` and `scope` attribute to observe the difference.

```
query = gdata.docs.service.DocumentQuery( categories=['folder|document'], params={'showfolders': 'true'} )
documents_feed = gd_client.Query(query.ToUri())
if documents_feed :
    for document_entry in documents_feed.entry:
        print document_entry.title.text + ' : ' + document_entry.resourceId.text
        print '<br>'
        acl_feed = gd_client.GetDocumentListAclFeed(document_entry.GetAclLink().href)
        for acl_entry in acl_feed.entry:
            print '%s - %s (%s)' % (acl_entry.role.value, acl_entry.scope.value, acl_entry.scope.type)
```

And here's the results:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-TOsiduiDksbkVlWXRtc2lSN00

I assumed that, the file or folder that's labeled as 'shared', will have it's `scope.type = default`
and the difference between a 'public on the web' and 'anyone with the link' is the 'reader' attribute in the `scope.value`

Although I can loop through the feed-entries to get all the 'shared' ones, I think I'd rather not and that it's more efficient to have that filtering inside the query.

I've been stuck on this for days. Could anyone tell me what are the correct params for this?